# select a specific digit from an integer - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing a math division of i.e 50 /6 and the outcome is 8,33333. I want to take the first digit 8 set it as output in another cell of the worksheet and then subtract it from the 8,3333. The final outcome on another cell should be 0,3333. How can i remove the ones (or tens) on the left of the decimal point for the above number?

Comment: So did you try any code at all? This seems pretty basic

Comment: I don't see any question marks anywhere in your "question"....

Comment: I was trying the following:   Dim trim As Integer
    trim = Range("C9").Value
    trim Mod 10

Comment: Dim trim As Integer
    trim = Range("C9").Value
    trim Mod 10

Comment: The question is how can a get the 8 out of the 8,3333?

Comment: No, the question is "how can you *improve your question* so it's not down-voted and closed?"  Currently, this question is unclear and very poor quality.  I suggest you delete it then carefully read [help] and [ask] and come back and try again after that.

Comment: You do not need VBA for this, just guessing, but I think you look for
x-int(x) oder Mod(x,1)

Answer (score 0):

Using and example for a similar case i found from another user in stackoverflow i did the following:

```
Dim trim As Integer
trim = Range("C9")
While trim >= 100
trim = trim \ 10
Wend
Range("C10").Value = trim
```

My original number is 8,33333 which was in cell C9. trim is the digits left of the decimal separator. So the output is trim=8.